# Javascript Project | Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html

now i have an idea for a project that i would like to work on and i know it is possible with software languages such as c# or c++

However i wanted to know if it would be actually do-able with web languages such as php and javascript:

I need to be able plug my phone in to my computer with a usb cable and using php/js i need to detect the phone thats been plugged in and detect some data. Now thats the first idea im not sure is possible.

Next i need to record strokes on the phone and macro it to repeat on the plugged phone, in case you dont know what i mean:

1- records prerecorded hand strokes to for example navigate to the setting option on the phone (via touchscreen) then changes a setting.

2- when phone is plugged in, it does the actions (aka keystrokes or touches on the touchscreen)

So is this actually possible with php/js? how if it is?

Thanks guys/girls, let me know for more info if you need it.

Comment: Do you already know C# or C++? Should the backend be coded with php?

Comment: PHP and JS are focussed on *web development*. This task has zero to do with web, so those are probably not the *best* languages to do this in (even if this may somehow be possible).

Comment: @Wolle Well that is the question my friend, is PHP/js able to do such tasks? or will i have to stick to c# or c++

Comment: @deceze yes exactly, and it would be a web application.

Comment: Can you maybe tell why do you wanna use PHP/JS... maybe there is a better solution for your requirement.

Comment: @danizmax i have stronger knowledge in these languages then c# or c++

Comment: So this is all supposed to happen in a browser? Then PHP has zero to do with it, only Javascript, and Javascript in a browser doesn't have access to low-level interfaces like USB. So, no, not possible.

Comment: @deceze PHP has nothing to do with the browser? i dont get it.

Comment: Nope. PHP sits on the server and spits out HTML text (or whatever else). It never touches a browser.

Comment: @deceze so my question is can PHP be used to detect USB/phones?

Comment: I really dont know in php, but you can try with to see for https://www.npmjs.org/package/usb or search nodejs usb in the web, but the comment of @deceze is true

Comment: Probably, but not a phone that is connected to a computer on which PHP doesn't run. PHP runs on the server, probably halfway around the globe, and the client runs a web browser accessing a website. PHP can't reach halfway around the globe into the USB port of the guy with the browser.

Comment: @deceze i am confident you dont know what you are talking about, you say half way around the globe almost as if your expecting a cable to go around the world, have you heard of the internet?servers?

Comment: OK, let's take a step back and *you* please clarify what you're talking about. There are *typically* two parties to a PHP/JS app: the server, on which PHP runs, and the client, on which a browser and JS runs. Both are not typically the same machine. Into which do you want to plug your phone then?

Comment: @deceze: Good question! This needs to be clarified first!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this script](https://gist.github.com/ahutchings/51342), which means that it is possible to communicate with serial/USB device. But You would still need to write a server for the android to communicate with it.

So In any case:

- only PHP/JS - **no**
- PHP/JS + Java/Android - **yes**
- PHP/JS + Java/C/C++ (for non android phones) - **yes**

Regards

Comment: Who said the OP is using an android smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible guys. Don't discourage him.

User3714214, since you are saying you have stronge knowledge in c# rather than php, i would strongly suggest you with sticking to c#.

Create an [ASP.NET Web API Project](http://www.asp.net/web-api). That's gonna be your API, running on your environment (where you gonna plug in your phone), which can easily communicate with your client-browsers of your network.

The theoretical background of the steps need to be done:

- Detect via C# weather a phone is plugged in (You can list connected devices using Windows Portable Devices API)
- Inform the clients browser that a phone is plugged in. (via AJAX or preferably websockets)
- Keep up the communication via websockets (TCP/IP). You can receive information and send information to you Backend-API (for example keystrokes).

**EDIT -** I know this answer is very vague, but if there are any specific parts you have problems with, just ask! :)

Answer (score 0):

Piecing together your information, it sounds like you want this:

```
+------------+                                  +---------+
| Web Server |                                  | Browser |
|  with PHP  | --------- THE INTERNET --------- | with JS |
+------------+                                  +---------+
                                                     |
                                                     |
                                                    USB
                                                   cable
                                                     |
                                                     |
                                                 +-------+
                                                 | Phone |
                                                 +-------+
```

Then: no, there's nothing you can do. PHP is not even on the same machine that the USB cable is plugged into, so there's nothing it can do. Javascript *would* be running on the same machine as the USB port, but Javascript running sandboxed in a browser doesn't have access to USB ports, or anything other than the browser's DOM, really. So it cannot do anything either.

What you'd need is a native client on the machine that the phone is plugged into, a Java applet, browser plugin with system level access or some such thing. That would certainly not be written in PHP and *likely* not written in Javascript, but rather C, C#, or some other system-native language. That plugin/native app *could* then communicate with a web service somewhere written in PHP; but PHP would have nothing directly to do with accessing the phone then either way. You'd also have to convince your users to install that native app/plugin first, which security conscious random users hopefully won't do.